# Bullet points in twitter bootstrap's popover content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display bullet points in the popover content but, for some reason, it is not showing.

The popover content is filled dynamically and the actual data comes from the server (please see notesFromServer variable)

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/108/

```
var verificationNotes = '';
var notesFromServer = "This is test note 1 \r\n This is test note 2";

if (notesFromServer != '') {
    verificationNotes += '<strong>Notes</strong></br>';
    var certNotesArr = notesFromServer.split('\r\n');
    verificationNotes += '<ul>' +
        $.each(certNotesArr, function (i, certNote) {
              verificationNotes += "<li>" + $.trim(certNote) + "</li>";
    });
    verificationNotes += '</ul>';                   
}

if (verificationNotes != '') {
    verificationNotes = '<span class="failed" data-toggle="popover" title="Note" data-content="' +    verificationNotes + '" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">View</span>';
}

$('#DynamicContent').append(verificationNotes);
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

[image]

**Expectation:**

The "This is test note 1 and This is test note 2" should appear in separate bullet points.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra plus after `verificationNotes += '<ul>'`, it should be

```
var verificationNotes = '';
var notesFromServer = "This is test note 1 \r\n This is test note 2";

if (notesFromServer != '') {
    verificationNotes += '<strong>Notes</strong></br>';
    var certNotesArr = notesFromServer.split('\r\n');
    verificationNotes += '<ul>';
        $.each(certNotesArr, function (i, certNote) {
              verificationNotes += "<li>" + $.trim(certNote) + "</li>";
    });
    verificationNotes += '</ul>';                   
}

if (verificationNotes != '') {
    verificationNotes = '<span class="failed" data-toggle="popover" title="Note" data-content="' +    verificationNotes + '" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">View</span>';
}

$('#DynamicContent').append(verificationNotes);
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Comment: Good catch. I don't know how I missed it. + 1 from me.

Comment: yeah, thats one of those that you'll stare at for an hour and it will drive you crazy! it happens to everyone!